# Unable to install MongoDB 3.4 on Debian stretch

Tags: mongodb, debian-stretch

I added mongodb repo to source list:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main
```

Then `apt-get update`.

When I try to install `mongodb-org` I'm getting this:

```
root@ns:~# aptitude install mongodb-org
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos{ab} mongodb-org-server{ab} mongodb-org-shell{ab} mongodb-org-tools{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 66.7 MB of archives. After unpacking 269 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mongodb-org [Not Installed]                        
2)     mongodb-org-mongos [Not Installed]                 
3)     mongodb-org-server [Not Installed]                 
4)     mongodb-org-shell [Not Installed]                  
5)     mongodb-org-tools [Not Installed]                  



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

but `aptitude search libssl` gives me:

```
root@ns:~# aptitude search libssl
p   libssl-dev                                                                                                                      - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files                                                                                         
p   libssl-doc                                                                                                                      - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation                                                                                 
p   libssl-ocaml                                                                                                                    - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)                                                                                                     
v   libssl-ocaml-4e458                                                                                                              -                                                                                                                                          
p   libssl-ocaml-dev                                                                                                                - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL                                                                                                               
v   libssl-ocaml-dev-4e458                                                                                                          -                                                                                                                                          
p   libssl1.0-dev                                                                                                                   - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files                                                                                         
i   libssl1.0.2                                                                                                                     - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries                                                                                          
i   libssl1.1                                                                                                                       - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
```

So my question is: how to install MongoDB 3.4 on Debian 9 from some trusted repository?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `jessie-backports`

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

This works for all MongoDB 3.x versions

Comment: Would love to have a way which is directly aimed to stretch instead of using jessie-backports when it's stretch and not jessie :/

Comment: @Hamburml Until there is no official build I think there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

Here is what helped me.

**root@7576d987a795:/#**  wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u6_amd64.deb

**root@7576d987a795:/#** sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u6_amd64.deb

After doing above steps i am able to install

**root@7576d987a795:/#** apt-get install mongodb-org-tools

Comment: Are you aware of the security implications of your proposal? If so, please take the time to add some lines explaining them.

Comment: I know having libssl1.0.0 is vulnerable for memory buffer overflow and it can be used to perform Denial of Services by Remote Code Injection.
My Answer is just to provide a solution although after resolution i recommend to update libraries to libssl1.0.2 which has patch for ubuntu 16.04.
Please add if i miss anything and thanks for raising this valuable concern

Comment: deb8u10 is the version I'm finding now.

Answer (score 0):

You can build it yourself here:
https://pages.corifeus.com/github/docker-debian-testing-mongodb-stable

Answer (score 0):

Download the `libssl1.1` package from this url [link](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb) then install the package

```sh
sudo dpkg -i <pkg you downloaded>
```

Then mongodb should just install